# Удалить конкретную часть текст в jquery или javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, текст

Я пытаюсь сделать простую задачу - это удалить конкретную часть текста, средствами jquery или javascript, но используя метод **replace** я не могу получить нужного мне результата. А именно вернуть текст после удаления конкретного символа. Т.е. то, что мне нужно удаляется (проверил через консоль), но в dom ничего не меняется. Так же, использовал **return**. Не помогает. Не могу понять, в чем я ошибаюсь.

```
<div class="header"><a href="#">Это просто текст</a></div>
```

Например, нужно удалить слово "просто", и вернуть "Это текст".

```
$('.header a').text().replace("просто", "");
```

Это работает для меня, но в dom ничего не меняет. Подскажите что не так? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не изменяете, а только получаете

```
$('.header a').text($('.header a').text().replace("просто", ""));
```